# Update teams Custom Tabs when it's not focused

Tags: javascript, microsoft-teams

Actually I'm developing a custom tab that needs to be updated via web sockets.

The problem is that when user change tab or app ( for example quit the custom tab app to use chat feature in teams ) the application get "killed" and it does not intercepte the data emit from server using web socket then update the view.

My use case is to update the view when server push data even when the tab is not focused.

Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Your tab gets updated everytime you open it. If you are planning to update the tab in the background, then that tab will automatically get updated when you visit the teams tab.

Comment: The problem is if data is sent to tab via websocket to the tab and if tab is not active, the socket will not intercept data and when user open the tab he will not get this datq

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT, If tab is not focused, does it's code still run in background ? websocket in client side will still listen to server pushes and app will update view ?

Comment: This is not possible. The tab is not running when it's not in view.

Comment: What is the best way to be able to update a tab that's not focused, in realtime ? the only actual workaround is to use service workers

Answer (score 1):

I think there's confusion between the idea of a "tab" in Teams versus a "tab" in the browser. In the browser, you can have a tab open, but be ***active*** on another tab. In that case, a websocket could be running, updating the content so that when a user goes back to the tab, it's already updated.

In contrast, in Teams, when a user views a tab, it's effectively loaded into an iframe. When the user browses away, the iframe is destroyed, and when they come back, the iframe it recreated, and the page -completely reloaded- again. As a result, there is *no need*, and it is *not possible* to "push" data to the tab when it's not in focus. However, when it ***is*** in focus/being used by the user, you can certainly keep it up to date using, for example, signalr.

Comment: exactly , And here's my issue, I have an app that is communicating using signalR with the backend. I would keep this "realtime architecture", otherwise I should request last update from server when tab get focused and keep using websockets when it's in-focus mode. I want to avoid this by using only websocket. do you think using service worker could solve this issue ?

Comment: no, I don't think it will help, but also remember that Teams is a multi-client tool. I use all 3 modes regularly - desktop, web, and mobile, and this would not work at all in that case as they would not be in sync

Comment: Teams  desktop is a web app wrapped in Electron instance so It should be the same